# check if receiver number have iMessage enabled in apple script?

Tags: applescript, imessage, ichat

I am creating an apple script that will send iMessages to some numbers,

I want to check if those numbers have iMessage or not before sending it.
How could i achieve that in script editor? The following is the script to send the iMessage

```
tell application "Messages"
    set theBuddy to buddy "the receiver number here" of service "my service"
    send "Washer Done! :)" to theBuddy
end tell
```

still need to check if the receiver will be able to receive it or not before sending.
Any help?

Regards,

Comment: Hey....Did you find your answer??